# Strange java command line folder path issue

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line-arguments

I have an application that receives a path as a command line argument. The path can contain spaces, so it can be sended with quotes. I need to verify if this path is correct, so I execute 'exists' method from 'File' class:

```
public static void main (String... args) {
  System.out.println("arg=" + args[0]);
  File f = new File(args[0]);
  System.out.println("exists=" + f.exists());
}
```

When I run the application with the follow arguments, I obtain this results (assume that "c:\folder" exists). Pay attention with final slash and quotes:

```
> java Test c:\folder
args=c:\folder
exists=true

> java Test c:\folder\
args=c:\folder\
exists=true

> java Test "c:\folder"
args=c:\folder
exists=true

> java Test "c:\folder\"
args=c:\folder
exists=false
```

I don't understand what's happens with last example. First in args result don't print final slash and then File class say that path doesn't exists. Second example without quotes works well.
Argument path has a free user edition, so it's possible that can include quotes (if path has folder with spaces) and a final slash.

Comment: \" is an escaped ". Research character escaping.

Comment: did you manage to fix the problem?

Comment: It seems that talex solution works, but two slashes at the end It's a bit ugly. Anyway I haven't found any better way to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not java issue but your shell. `\` act as escape character if it is used before `"` in Windows. To work around that you can write parameter as `"c:\folder\\"`

It is also strange output. When i did the same I got `args=c:\folder"` in last case.